# Why does the EU-UK trade deal have the 7-bit ASCII table as an appendix?

Tags: brexit, international-relations

I just noticed this on Twitter:

https://twitter.com/thejsa_/status/1343291595899207681

> Fun fact: the EU-UK post Brexit trade deal text includes a copy of the 7-bit ASCII table on page 977, just in case you happen to need it

[image]

Related tweets also show references to Netscape Navigator 4.x and SHA-1, which could probably be attributed to outdated templates, but what specific regulation(s) does the EU-UK trade deal have that requires the inclusion of a 7-bit ASCII table?

Comment: Beth Johanssen took one to Mars... never know when it could come in handy...

Comment: 'Characters' 123 and 125 look seriously odd. JSON escaping issue?

Comment: @abligh don't know why it would be JSON, but heh, yes, it does look like someone screwed that up. I'm waiting for someone to actually follow this table and have their system not work.

Comment: Noting what other people have said about character sets. The mention of Netscape Navigator 4 could possibly be something to do with the fact that- IIRC- it defined its scripting in terms of ECMAscript (i.e. a European standard) which I suspect wasn't mentioned in later versions of Mozilla software.

Comment: The presentation is unlike any I have ever seen. Row-major order, and strictly decimal. Also, no clear indication of which (if any) of those "empty" cells is supposed to represent the space character. Pile that on top of the wonkiness in cells 123 and 125, and it makes me wonder whether the person who prepared it even knows or cares what ASCII is used for.

Comment: Seems to me that they could have simply referenced the appropriate ISO standard. That's what standards are for.

Comment: Well, since everything else in Europe is metric, might as well go metric instead of binary (and by extension, a more proper 2^3 = 8 or 2^4 = 16 characters per row or column). Amazing they haven't gone to decimal time (I know, it has been tried...). But seriously, someone was given a table to create **who had no clue themselves, and no proofreader or editor who had any clue either**. Welcome to the real world folks, mistakes all over *and nobody cares who can actually do anything about it*. :-(

Comment: Character 34 is wrong also. It should be a double quote. Instead it's a single quote that looks slightly different from the one in cell 39. I suppose they made the table in Microsoft Word with smart quotes turned on.

Comment: Anyone else find it ironic that the EU-UK trade deal uses the American Standard Code for Information Interchange from the American National Standards Institute?

Comment: @GlenYates gotto as an American, I absolutely love American cultural imperialism... :)

Comment: Despite having 4.5 years to sort this out it appears that a lot of it was cobbled together at the last minute and not checked.

Comment: So we can turn our back on LATIN-1 along with everything else european.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The problem with Latin-1 is that it only covers the most western of European countries. It's hard to cover all of Europe with only 200 or so (ignoring control characters) values. Czech uses ISO/IEC 8859-2 (AKA Latin-2), Malta is Latin-3 and Greece is ISO-8859-7, and most of those lack the Euro symbol. They are also all based on US-ASCII as a strict superset of the encoding.

Comment: @SolomonSlow So typical bureaucrats?

Comment: @benrg: Honestly, the misuse of curly braces and smart quotes make me think this was made in LaTeX, by someone who has no idea how LaTeX works... but I find it difficult to imagine them actually doing that, so *shrug*.

Comment: Now I just wonder what they included Netscape in the deal for...

Answer (score 25):

If you scroll up one page, you'll see it is part of an appendix to "Chapter 2 (exchange of dactyloscopic data)", or in other words, that data format for representing fingerprints.  Certain fields in this data format are text fields, which are meant to be using ASCII characters.

Comment: So taken out of context?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Well, "what is the context?" is really the crux of this question.

Answer (score 12):

@Joe C is correct. ASCII code is also referenced elsewhere regarding standards and protocols for exchanging various types of data, including, for example, DNA records. All such usages require a commonly agreed precise reference, which is the table in the appendix. See pages 924-925, 934-935, and others. Ensuring everyone knows they are using the same "language" when sharing data is a matter requiring serious precision in international treaties.

Comment: "serious precision"... and then they messed up the curly braces. Wonder what other quality issues are hidden in these papers :)

Comment: Some of the EU countries have significant cultural use of Cyrillic, so it's entirely reasonable to have an unambiguous statement of the character set to be used. I'm just surprised that the French didn't insist that it included the accented vowels that they habitually use.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Everyone expects to use UTF-8 and it "just works" (except when it doesn't). I guess the unambiguous statement of the character  set is because of the need to match entries in legacy databases.

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Perhaps. But remember that the EU predates (common use of) UTF-8, and that as well as Cyrillic there are various "not quite ASCII" codepages... so it makes entire sense to define a single baseline encoding.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Definitely. But Cyrillic IMHO has nothing to do with this - commonly used pre-UTF-8 Bulgarian codepage *was* ASCII compatible. And common EU dactyloscopic database might well predate Bulgaria's membership in the EU. (and there was Greece anyway). My gut feeling is that the dactyloscopic database (like many, many legacy systems) is ASCII only and essientialy unupgradable.

Comment: @dlatikay And no control codes. And the space character is... where exactly? And the table ends with the code position 129? Oh my...

Comment: @RadovanGarabík Thanks for the comment on Bulgaria in particular. However I /did/ say /cultural/ use of Cyrillic, and was trying to distinguish its use by minorities in e.g. Poland from the Roman alphabet's broader acceptance. Whatever, as pointed out by others: the document is a bit sloppy even if the intintion is fairly clear.

Comment: It is somewhat unfortunate that even the American imperialism was not able to dictate the English language and 7 bit ASCII as the only valid text format to store in computers. That would have prevented many a headache ;-).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Oh, American imperialism went a long way towards that goal. For the longest time, the Unicode Consortium seriously believed that 65,536 characters would be enough for everyone, because they thought that Unicode would only be needed for the international exchange of documents, and everyone would just use "whatever" code page for domestic computing. If they had realized in advance that they would need to accommodate all of CJK, then UTF-16 probably never would have existed.